# Generic Lists within the team site

Tags: team-sites

I have a custom list which shows the latest news of a department in an orgnisation. This list is in the top level site collection. I want to create a new generic list and use the same content types across the organisation. In this way, I can re-use the same content type for multiple departments when displaying the department related latest news driven from the same content type of the root level site collection List settings. How do I create a generic list content type and access that in the child level sites. I would like to access the each list (department wise) with reference to URL and the list name of the department. Please suggest me the best to achieve this.

Please note that this is a for Team site template which is used as a top level site template.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the content type at the Site Collection root site, so that it is accessible on each subsite.

Then, you can add that content type to a list. Finally, if you wish, you can save the list as a template, so that you can easily create new lists that already have that correct content type included.

Comment: Thank Jussi. I got this now. I am able to find this out.